# Why hasn't my ban on asking questions been lifted

Tags: support, bug, post-ban

I know that I was getting lots of down-votes and close-votes on my questions and that's why I was banned. But the thing is, My "positive contributions" **do** outweigh my negative ones.

When I asked those "bad" questions I was new to the site - my rep was around 30 - and didn't know much about the site either. Now I correct *other* people when they ask "bad" questions.

For the last 8 days I have been answering questions, earned **500+** rep (5/6ths of my total rep) - I've answered more than 40 questions with around 20 accepted, and have had 34 upvotes, and only 2 downvotes (all in 8 days) - and still, I can't ask questions! why?

Comment: Do you have links to any samples of questions where you have landed negative?  The answer to why you are banned now depends on why you were banned in the first place, and I don't see those questions in your list of questions on the main site.

Comment: Note that downvoted deleted questions still count.

Comment: @Brad no, sadly not. a few were deleted too

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I deleted most downvoted questions **before** 30 days

Comment: @RandomUser Which means they won't affect your rep, but they are still taken into consideration by the question ban algorithm.

Comment: Remember, positive rep doesn't necessarily mean overall more positive actions than negative, and i doubt the system is doing a 1:1 comparison to see that you've made more positive contributions than negative anyway, there's likely a weighting system involved. an upvote gives you 10 rep, where as a downvote gives you only 3, therefore it's certainly possible to be doing more negative than positive and still be gaining rep, especially when you start deleting things (which may even make the negative impact worse.)

Comment: Per your edit, answering that question would require giving out information on the algorithm that gives out question bans, so i doubt you'll ever get an answer to that other than you simply haven't performed enough positive actions to outweigh the negative.